# AWK command help

Tags: unix, awk

I have a homework assignment and this is the question.

Using awk create a command that will display each field of a specific file.

Show the date at the beginning of the file with a line between and a title at the head of the output.

I have read the book and can't quite figure it out, here is what I have:

```
BEGIN {
{"date" | getline d }
{ printf "\t %s\n,d }
{ print "Heading\n" }
{ print "=====================\n }
}
{ code to display each field of file??? }
```

Answer (score 3):

Some tips about awk:

The format of an awk program is

```
expression { action; ... }
expression { action; ... }
...
```

If the expression evaluates to true, then the action block is executed. Some examples of expressions:

```
BEGIN       # true before any lines of input are read
END         # true after the last line of input has been read
/pattern/   # true if the current line matches the pattern
NR < 10     # true if the current line number is less than 10
```

etc. The expression can be omitted if you want the action to be performed on every line.

So, your BEGIN block has too many braces:

```
BEGIN {
    "date" | getline d 
    printf("\t %s\n\n",d)
    print "Heading" 
    print "====================="
}
```

You could also write

```
BEGIN {
    system("date")
    print ""
    print "Heading" 
    print "====================="
}
```

or execute the date command outside of awk and pass the result in as an awk variable

```
awk -v d="$(date)" '
    BEGIN {
        printf("%s\n\n%s\n%s\n", 
            d,
            "heading",
            "======")
    }
```

The print command implicitly adds a newline to the output, so `print "foo\n"; print "bar"` will print a blank line after "foo". The printf command requires you to add newlines into your format string.

Can't help you more with "code to print each field". Luuk shows that `print $0` will print all fields. If that doesn't meet your requirements, you'll have to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

```
{"date" | getline d }
```

why not simply print current date
   { print strftime("%y-%m-%d %H:%M"); }

and for:

```
{ code to display each field of file??? }
```

simply do

```
{ print $0; }
```

if you only wanted the first field you should do:

```
{ print $1; }
```

if you only want the second field:

```
{print $2; }
```

if you want only the last field:

```
{print $NF;}
```

Because NF is the number of field on a line......